# Liferay migration from local to live site

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

[image]

I downloaded Liferay files from a livesite to setup a local environment for some local development. After downloading the files, I run the the catalina file (`./catalina.sh start`) But unfortunately I got a 404 error.

I'm not sure where to start in setting up Liferay locally.

- I think there are some initial settings that I should be doing as I had moved from live server to a local machine.
- I think I need to also connect my database. I now have a local copy of the database and is already imported on MySQL. I just need to connect them (im guessing entering my user and password for the database).
- Other than downloading the files and starting up the server, I really haven't done anything else yet as I am not sure what setting and configuration I should be doing.

I'm new to Liferay, I apologize for my silliness.

---

**Edit**

my `portal-ide.properties` settings:

[image]

Comment: See portal-developer.properties in tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes

Comment: Hi Mark,

I've checked out the 2 properties files and I see no problem or I think I can configure. Any ideas?

Thanks!

http://i50.tinypic.com/9rhymw.jpg

Thanks

Comment: Do you have found the `developer.properties`?

Comment: I'd try to start Liferay without providing any settings via properties files so it'll use the internal HSQLDB database and see if it starts without exceptions. If that works than I would try to add properties one by one, restart Liferay and see when it stops working. At that point you should get an relatively clear exception in the Liferay log files.

Comment: Hi Fimez, thanks for the advice. Which of the property file are you advising me to disable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See portal-ext.properties or someelse *.properties file in the root folder of portal.

For error details,  see the log file at liferay/tomcat/logs/catalina.out